# Grid for Android

Tags: android, layout, background, grid, border

I'd don't know how to create a grid for android, where I can add borders and background on each boxes.

What is the best way to do it ?

For the moment I have a RelativeLayout where I put some Button in, but it's difficult to modify them easily.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look these link.

It might help you.

**[Link1](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/)**

**[Link2](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/)**

For setting border on each imageview inside the `GridLayout`.

Create a `layout` xml file in res/drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" /></shape>
```

Add the background to imageview:

```
android:background="@drawable/xmlFileName"
```

By programmatically:

```
imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xmlFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already seen these link and they didn't really helped me. I'd like to make a sort of sudoku grid.

Comment: @thomash check it first one You will be able to use grid layout in android.

Comment: Here is the same problem I said to Alex, I don't want to put an image, but a layout with border and background. Else this link is the solution to my problem ;)

Comment: Thanks it works ! But can I modify the background color programmatically without removing the border or I must create as xml files as I have differents backgrounds ? Edit : I'm trying it on a TextView

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what you need, but have you checked out the GridView? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Yes I've checked this, but not that much. What layout I can put in which I can add border and background ?